# Recode different numbers to NAs in R

Tags: r, missing-data, recode

I have a big dataset with 760 variables. I would like to recode the numbers in NAs and I have always used this simple thing:

```
dataset[dataset==99] <- NA
```

But this time I have a problem: in this dataset missing values are different numbers! Some missing values are 9, some 99, 999, 9999, and 9999999... In some cases when 9 is a plausible value for a variable, the missing value is 99 or more. This is a really bad data set (made for SPSS), but I can't change it. I could find out which variable has which missing value. I used the function from library matrixStats::colMaxs but I don't know how can I recode the right missing values in NAs. Any ideas?

Maximal values for each column below. You can see that in some columns there are no missing, but such numbers like 9 or 99 are still plausible (for example the first columns).

```
[1]      276     2068 20680101   206801        4       99        9

 [8]        9       99        9        9        9        9        9
 [15]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
 [22]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
 [29]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
 [36]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
 [43]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
 [50]        9        9        9        9        9       99       99
 [57]       99       99       99       99        9        9        9
 [64]        9        9        9        9        9     9999     9999
 [71]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
 [78]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
 [85]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
 [92]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
 [99]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
[106]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
[113]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
[120]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
[127]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
[134]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
[141]        9        9        0        1        4        2        1
[148]   999999        9   999999        9   999999        9   999999
[155]        9        9     9999     9999       34        9        9
[162]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
[169]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
[176]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
[183]        9     -Inf     -Inf      999      999      999      999
[190]      999        9        9        9        9        9        9
[197]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
[204]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
[211]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
[218]        9        9        9        9        9     -Inf     -Inf
[225]     -Inf        9     -Inf     -Inf     -Inf        9     -Inf
[232]     -Inf     -Inf        9       99      135        9        9
[239]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
[246]     -Inf        9        9        9        9        9        9
[253]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
[260]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
[267]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
[274]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
[281]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
[288]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
[295]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
[302]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
[309]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
[316]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
[323]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
[330]        9        9        9        9        9       99        9
[337]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
[344]        9        9        9        9        9        9        9
[351]        9        9        9       99        5        5        3
[358]        5        5        5        6        5        3        3
[365]        3        3
```

Comment: Hello Magdalena! Seems like you are a bit confused about what the data means? We can't help you with that. First make clear what you want to do with that table and define it using clear unambiguous terms in plain English. Then we can help you how to do it in R :-)

Comment: We can't really tell you what logic to use to decide if, say, `999` is a missing or plausible value for a certain column. If you come up with an idea, we can help you implement it. Perhaps looking at a table of values for each column can help you decide, `lapply(your_data, table)`. But you know much more about your data than we do, so we can't tell you about its meaning.

Comment: If you have the original SPSS dataset you can try reading the data with `haven::read_spss()`. It'll keep the labels so you can know which values correspond to missings

Comment: I agree to the other commenters hard to say something about your data (as we don't know it. Depending on the structure of the data calculating some kind of median or 3rd quartile bounds and deducting from there, if a 99, 999 should be an NA might be an idea.